# Why does slow decay decelerate a motor faster than fast decay does in a H Bridge?

Tags: current, dc-motor, h-bridge, inductance, back-emf

I understand how the terms slow decay and fast decay relate to current rather than angular acceleration, but I am currently having a lot of trouble understanding why slow decay decelerates the motor faster than fast decay.

If fast decay reduces the induced current flowing through the motor faster than slow decay does, and the magnetic field generated by the current is what allows the motor to spin, then why does allowing the induced current to flow for a longer timer result in quicker deceleration?

Comment: I am confused. Can you give us a specific case study, eg, TB6612FNG: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/TB6612FNG.pdf.

Comment: In this type of scenario voltage is induced and not current.

Comment: Consider the two extreme cases of a motor open-circuited, and the same motor short circuited.

Comment: @Andyaka Doesnt the induced emf created by the inductor create a current.

Comment: The voltage is induced and, the current that may flow is due to normal ohms law when the circuit is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slow decay shorts the terminals of the motor, by decreasing equivalent resistance, resulting in an increase in current. This increase in current results in a back emf in the motor windings—which creates a large current in the opposite direction—which stops the motor quickly. Back emf is relative to the change in current, so the short will cause a very quick increase, which the back emf will fight fiercely, initially. Any decay after will be fought with a decaying back emf, resulting in a much slower current decay.

On the other hand, the induced current from the motor, in fast decay, is fought with a consistent resistance in the wire, consistent voltage drops across the transistors, and a consistent voltage provided by the power supply. This results in a very quick, yet consistent gradual decay in current. The gradual nature of fast decay combined with the motor's inertia allows the motor to coast as opposed to an abrupt stop.

[image: Chart]

Comment: _"This increase in current results in a back emf in the motor windings which stops the motor quickly."_ - Current creates torque. The _torque_ stops the motor. The short _prevents_ back-emf from appearing (actually it is dropped across the winding resistance). Without a short the motor freely generates voltage without producing current, so it coasts when not powered.